# Can a default new function be created for all Ecto models using a macro?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like all of my models to have access to a `new` convenience function that returns a custom changeset.

Something like:

```
def new(attrs) do
  changeset(%__MODULE__{}, attrs)
end
```

That way, when I need changeset validation, I could call:

`Project.Model.new(%{param1: "param1"})`

Instead of:

`Project.Model.changeset(%Model{}, %{param1: "param1"})`

The problem I run into is that when I implement the following macro:

```
defmodule Project.Model do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      use Ecto.Schema
      import Ecto.Changeset
      def new(attrs) do
        changeset(%__MODULE__{}, attrs)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

... it doesn't work, because Ecto's `schema "model" do ... end` needs to be compiled before my `use Project.Model` statement otherwise I'll get an error which basically says my module does not have a struct defined.

I could limit the macro simply to the `new` function and place it in the middle of the module that uses it but that seems confusing.

Any ideas?

By request, full code below:

*Once again, the purpose of all this, is to have models that `use Project.Model` gain a convenience function `new` that accepts attributes and puts them inside a `changeset` so that they will be validated before database insertion.*

The error I get, as some have alluded to, is that `schema` must be expanded before I can use `__MODULE__` in my macro because the struct will not have yet been defined.

**project/user.ex**

```
defmodule Project.User do
  use Project.Model

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:email, :first_name, :last_name])
    |> validate_required([:email, :first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

**project/model.ex**

```
defmodule Project.Model do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      use Ecto.Schema
      import Ecto.Changeset
      def new(attrs) do
        changeset(%__MODULE__{}, attrs)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Try this: Put the ‘use Project.Model’ line just after the schema definition. Also you don’t need to use Ecto.Schema in your macro since the model ‘using’ that macro will already be using a schema.

Comment: @Badu I think putting `use Project.Model` after the schema definition is likely the right answer, it just seems strange. Would that convention confuse other developers? Also, I put `use Ecto.Schema` in my macro because I know I'll need it in all of my models. Is that wrong?

Comment: As you inferred from the error you got, the reason is you are using struct syntax ```%__MODULE__{}``` which is only made available after the schema is defined. Remember when you ```use Ecto.Schema``` a struct is automatically defined for the module with the given fields. In other words, your macro (by using %__MODULE__{}) depends on the schema definition. Think of using macros as a way of inserting pieces of code into your module and if the code has dependencies then those dependencies must be present for the code to compile. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a struct before it's defined, you can try this trick:

```
  def new(attrs) do
    changeset(struct(__MODULE__), attrs)
  end
```

`changeset` is something you should define per model (and might have a different shape) so I'm not sure it's a good idea to use it inside `new` in a general manner.

Comment: Will doing so validate against a defined changeset? What are the reasons to deviate from the base `changeset(struct, attrs)` signature? Doesn't all changeset behavior follow the `|> cast`, `|> validate_required`, etc. pattern within the block?

Comment: Also, still getting the same error when I switch from `changeset` to `struct`. Error is thrown at the `use` statement: `Project.Model.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct Project.Model`

Comment: No, if you're sure your changeset will always have the same signature, you can use it there, but I think it kinda breaks the pattern. My main point was that it's possible to create struct kinda lazily, without calling structure constructor explicitly. I'm not sure why it's not working for you, I tried and it worked for me.

Comment: Could you show the full code? `Project.Model` and where you're using it. Cause it seems like `__MODULE__` is refering to `Project.Model` itself, which shouldn't be the case if you're calling it inside of macro.

Comment: The error you're seeing means that you tried to run that macro in context of Project.Model. Which I don't see happening in your code posted. If you're sure you want to use changeset, you can just replace content of new with `changeset(struct(__MODULE__), attrs)`

Comment: Ivan that worked! Does exactly what I wanted. If you update your answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Sure, updated. But bear in mind that this might not be the best thing to do. Normally when you create a `changeset` using `cast`, validations and all that stuff it is assumed, that you're dealing with external data. However `new` is conventionally a way to create new structure or object (in OOP languages) with some attributes, which is obviously controlled by the programmer, hence doesn't need validation or casting. What I would do, is sticking with plain struct(__MODULE__, attrs) (where attrs would be a map with atom keys) in new. But at the end of the day it's up to you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with this code is the order of macro to AST expansion. I doubt I understand why would you attempt to use the injected `#changeset` when you have a plain old good [`Ecto.Changeset.change/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#change/2) on hand. Just do:

```rb
defmodule Project.Model do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      use Ecto.Schema
      import Ecto.Changeset

      def new(attrs) do
        __MODULE__
        |> struct(%{})
        |> change(attrs)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and you should be all set since [`Ecto.Changeset.change/2`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.0.6/lib/ecto/changeset.ex#L368) is a normal function that won’t be attempted to expand to AST.

Comment: This will still break, cause `%__MODULE__{}` will try to expand. One has to use `struct(__MODULE__, ..)` to do it lazily.

Comment: @IvanYurov copy-paste leftover, thanks for the sharp eye. I have it fixed; though `struct` is an ugly hack, there should be just a module (as `change` accepts it.)

Comment: I'm not sure that change accepts the module, though. Anyways, I don't see the reason behind constructing a changeset in `new` either. I mean I see that this is exactly what OP wanted, but shouldn't it rather be a fresh structure instead? Also, why do you think using struct(mod, %{}) is a hack? It's public API, I don't see anything neither hacky nor ugly about it.

Comment: @IvanYurov yes, indeed, you are right, I don’t know why I ever thought it’s a hack.